# Does MSSQL currently have any features similar to "PERIOD" columns in SQL2011?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-database

I have a project where the PERIOD columns defined in the SQL2011 spec are the perfect solution.  Unfortunately, I am forced to use MSSQL 2008R2 (or possibly MSSQL 2012) as my database, which does not support this feature.

Is there any proprietary feature that resembles the PERIOD features in SQL2011 currently in MSSQL?  If not, any advice for the best way to try to implement something resembling it?

Comment: Does it **have** to be Microsoft SQL Server? PostgreSQL 9.2 will have support for that.

Comment: Playing a dummy, and not having direct and immediate access to the standard (or familiarity with PostgreSQL), could you describe what PERIODS does, and illustrate with an example of how you want to implement it? I think it would save a lot of people from going and learning it on their own and then trying to guess how you want to use it...

Comment: The clearest example of how PERIOD works in practice is in the following presentation (beginning on page 15): http://metadata-standards.org/Document-library/Documents-by-number/WG2-N1501-N1550/WG2_N1536_koa046-Temporal-features-in-SQL-standard.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Anchor Modelling](http://www.anchormodeling.com). I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, (a PERIOD equivalent) but databases implemented as an Anchor model can include bi-temporal aspects. The generated SQL code when exporting the model primarily supports MS SQL. Oracle is available too but a lot of work when into optimizing the schema, trigger and view SQL code for MS SQL. Maybe it'll help, maybe you can see how they implemented bi-temporal data in a way that works really well with MS SQL.